# Javascript - Move DIV Scrollbar to Top When iFrame SRC Changes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, scroll, scrolltop

re: http://www.gooplusplus.com/cost-of-living-compare-cities/

I made a relatively simple web site to make it easier to compare potential "expat" cities. There are links (target=iframe) for each city for cost of living data, wikipedia, expat blogs, climate info, and Google map.

The left column consists of several control links for each city.

The main window is a single **iframe within a DIV**. Iframe scrolling is set to OFF. **Scrolling is done using the iframe's DIV.** Iframe contents are from **external domains**.

The **problem:** if one scrolls down to view a long Wikipedia entry and then the user clicks on a new City link, the **iframe content position stays at the old DIV position**, which is not what is typically wanted.

The desired behavior (**Javascript**, not jQuery):

**Move the DIV's vertical scrollbar - go to the TOP of document whenever the iframe SRC document changes.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually much easier than with more complex web sites using iframes. For this simple web page, BODY and not the DIV control the scrolling.

```
<iframe src="numbeo.html" onLoad="window.scrollTo(0,0);" etc. >
```